# How to align content to the bottom of a div?

Tags: html, css

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gv4qd/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="a">
  <div id="b">bbb</div>
  <div id="c">ccc</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#a {
  border: 1px solid black;
   *zoom: 1;
}
#a:before, #a:after {
   display: table;
    content: "";
    line-height: 0;
}
#a:after {
  clear: both;
}

#b {
  float: left;
  font-size: 36px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#c {
  float: right;
  background-color: red;
}
```

I want the red box (`#c`) to be aligned to the bottom-right corner.

If I add `position:relative` to `#a` and `position:absolute;bottom:0;right:0` to `#c` it works, but as soon as I add it the blue box as well the container (`#a`) collapses. I don't know which is going to be taller, `#b` or `#c` so I want to apply the positioning to both of them. The usual clear-fix doesn't work on absolutely positioned elements.

So how do I position `#b` to the bottom-left, and `#c` to the bottom-right without collapsing the container div `#a`?

Comment: did you try `vertical-align`?

Comment: @SolèneLeVan: Yes, with `display:table-cell` too. Couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Wow this is a toughie... :{

Comment: +1, very good question. By the way, do you need IE support? Just wondering.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: Maybe IE9+. I'll be happy if I get it to work in *any* browser right now. Testing in Chrome 24 right now.

Comment: Is using javascript an option?

Comment: How about this? http://jsfiddle.net/gv4qd/3/

Comment: @Sanchit: I'd prefer not to, but if there are no other options, I guess so.

Comment: @3dgoo: It took some fiddling to get it just the way I wanted, but yes! That does seem to work! Thank you!

Comment: Can you post your solution Mark? I am curious.

Comment: @Sanchit: My real-world example is slightly more complex. Here's my solution, written in Jade and Less: http://jsfiddle.net/gaB7D/ I had to add an extra wrapper around the `ul` to get it right-aligned properly.

Comment: @Sanchit there are no tags there in your jsfiddle's html; it's just text.

Comment: @ZackT. I'm assuming that's actually directed at me...like I said, it's written in Jade. http://jade-lang.com/

Comment: @Sanchit so, can jsfiddle interpret jade? because, like I said, it just shows as text in the output.

Comment: @ZackT. No, it cannot, which is why I didn't post my solution originally. I was just sharing it with Sanchit since he said he was curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is pretty esoteric solution, but it works :)

Setting both #b and #c `inline-block` so they work with each other like regular inlines and we can use `vertical-align`. Then adding `text-align:justify;` to container and `:after` with `width:100%` to pull #b and #c to the left and right sides. Setting font to zero for container (and restore it in inner blocks) to avoid under/over-line and other gaps and set zero font to :after.

```
#a {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align:justify;
  font-size:0;
  line-height:0;
}
#a:after {
  content:"";
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%;
}

#b, #c {
  display:inline-block;
}

#b {
  vertical-align:top;
}
#c {
  vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

`font-size:0;` looks not working in IE, so we need little workaround with 1px negative margin:

```
/* ie fix */
#a {
  font:1px/0 sans-serif;
}
#b, #c {
  margin:0 0 -1px;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gv4qd/35/

Comment: In your second box "bbb" is top-aligned in Chrome. Should be in the bottom-left :-)

Comment: Ok, didn't get it first time. Just change vertical-align for #b to bottom http://jsfiddle.net/gv4qd/37/

Comment: Close...your `-1px` margin fix for IE actually pulls the boxes overtop of `#a`'s border in Chrome though.

Comment: Mostly fixed http://jsfiddle.net/gv4qd/42/ but in Chrome now one extra pixel on the right. Sorry, I can't find solution right now. You can filter IE styles with conditional comments.

Comment: With little more magic `letter-spacing:-1px;` it works, but I really don't like this solution and can't recommend it because of potential bugs. http://jsfiddle.net/gv4qd/43/

Comment: That looks right now. I did find another solution that uses `display:table` and `display:table-cell`...not sure if that's more or less likely to break.

Comment: Actually you can use a table, it is unbreakable but not semantic. For this task will be perfect flex positioning http://flexiejs.com/playground/, but now there is mess in specs and we should wait it stable and supported by browsers.

Answer (score 1):

After testing out a few different options, I found that using position:relative on the parent container allows the child tags to be positioned absolutely, yet relative to the parent, rather than the document window.

```
#a {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 500px;width:500px;
    position:relative;
    }

#b, #c{
       position:absolute;bottom:0;
      }
#b{
    left:0;
    font-size: 36px;
    background-color: blue;
    }

#c {
    right:0;
    background-color: red;
    }
```

Comment: As it stands, I wouldn't class this as an answer. Please _explain_ your solution, as well as giving it.

Comment: It works because you are giving fixed height.. which I assume what OP doesn't want.. (I am not sure as OP didn't mention it)..

Comment: I would also assume that the parent container would contain some content, if not a min-height would likely be used? But who knows..

Answer (score 1):

This should do it i believe

```
position: absolute;
top: auto;
bottom: 0px;
```

Unable to test it at the moment but will test later, just use the css on the div you wish to align at the bottom

Answer (score 1):

After some messing around this appears to work. The trick is to absolutely position `#a`, `#b` and `#c` and place all three in a relatively positioned div.

### HTML

```
<div id="alpha">
  <p>Here is a box to give the<br /> outer<br /> container<br /> some<br /> height</p>
  <div id="a">
    <div id="b">bbb</div>
    <div id="c">ccc</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#alpha {
  position: relative;

}

#a {
  border: 1px solid black;
   *zoom: 1;
  position:absolute;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  top:0;bottom:0;
}
#a:before, #a:after {
   display: table;
    content: "";
    line-height: 0;
}
#a:after {
  clear: both;
}

#b {
  font-size: 36px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
}

#c {
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
}
```

**JSFiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/mrmikemccabe/gv4qd/36/

I've placed a paragraph in the outer div to give the box some height. If you won't have anything in the outer div just declare a fixed height for the outer div in the CSS.

Comment: That's like `Maciej Paprocki`'s solution.. I wanted to avoid hard-coding a height (or using dummy content).

Comment: It differs from Maciej Paprocki's because there is an extra containing DIV. Surely `#a` will be in another container? With other things? Just give the container `position:relative` and #a, #b, #c `position:absolute` and it works. No need to define a height for `#a` which I believe is what you asked for.

Comment: Giving `#a` `position:relative` doesn't prevent it from collapsing though..I'm not sure how this is any better. This only works if you have some other content in `#alpha` to stretch it out, which I don't.

Comment: I didn't say give `#a` `position:relative`

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were referring to `#a` when you said "the container" as `#a` *was* the container in my original example. Regardless though, the rest still stands.

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
#a {
  border: 1px solid black;
  *zoom: 1;
}
#a:before, #a:after {
  display: table;
  content: "";
  line-height: 0;
}
#a:after {
 clear: both;
}

#b {
  float: left;
  font-size: 36px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#c {
   float: right;
   background-color: red;
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0; right:0;
   vertical-align:bottom;
 }
```

Comment: As it stands, I wouldn't class this as an answer. Please _explain_ your solution, as well as giving it.

Comment: This doesn't keep the #c div inside of the #a div. Not a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

Give auter div position:relative

Give inner div position:absolute and bottom:0px; left:0px; or whatever place you like.

it's very important to give outer div position:relative. if not sometimes it will be working sometimes not. And of course it will not work in very old internet explorer like everything.

absolute elements dont have height so if you can not use specified (like height:120px) you are f*****. You can do this only by javascript to check the height of one absolute element and second one and adding it with special margins.

to be sure which container is on top  you can use z-index.

I forgot theres another way. use fake duplicate content of both divs but it is a lot of work so it will be faster to do it with javascript.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned the absolute-positioning solution in my Q, but it collapses the container div, as you mentioned. I don't want to hard-code the height.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your css file:

```
   #a {
        border: 1px solid black;  
        position:relative;
       *zoom: 1;
    }
    #a:before, #a:after {
       display: table;
        content: "";
        line-height: 0;
    }
    #a:after {
      clear: both;
    }

    #b {
      float: left;
      font-size: 36px;
      background-color: blue;
    }

    #c {
        float: right;
        background-color: red;
        position: absolute;
        bottom:0px;
        right:0px;
    }
```

Comment: You didn't read the question clearly. You've absolute-positioned `#c` and not `#b` -- if you move the font-size from `#b` to `#c` the alignment gets messed up. Assume I don't know which text will be bigger/taller.